# Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tf.keras

```
model = Sequential([
                Dense(64, input_dim=X_train.shape[1]),
                Dense(64),
                Dense(32),
                Dense(32),
                Dense(16),
                Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') ])

for l in range(len(model.layers)):
print(l, model.layers[l])

getFeature = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
                    [model.layers[4].output])`
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 0 (missing previous layer metadata).
```

Comment: Please include explicitly your imports (edit your post accordingly).

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!